# why does function does not stop when a exception is raised (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class like this:

```
import threading
import time
import psutil
class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass
class Performance:
    def __init__(self, func, time_limit=20, except_return = None) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.except_return = except_return
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        process = psutil.Process()
        process.memory_info().rss
        process.memory_info().rss
        elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
        self.time_limit = time_limit + elapsed_time
        self.__init_time_waste = elapsed_time
    def handler(self):
        with open('Output.txt',mode='a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.writelines("Time Limited Exceeded!\n")
        raise TimeoutError("Time Limited Exceeded!")
    def run(self):
        def run_func():
            timer = threading.Timer(self.time_limit,self.handler)
            result = []
            start_time = 0
            before_memory = 0
            after_memory = 0
            elapsed_time = 0
            timer.start()
            try:
                start_time = time.perf_counter()
                process = psutil.Process()
                before_memory = process.memory_info().rss
                result = self.func()
                after_memory = process.memory_info().rss
                elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time - self.__init_time_waste
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                timer.cancel()
                return self.except_return
            else:
                timer.cancel()
                with open('Output.txt',mode='a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    f.writelines(f"Executing Time: {elapsed_time:.5f} \n")
                    f.writelines(f"Memory Used: {after_memory - before_memory} bytes \n")
                print(f"Executing Time: {elapsed_time:.5f}")
                print(f"Memory Used: {after_memory - before_memory} bytes")
            return result
        return run_func()
```

This class is used to limit the run time of a function and compute the memory used. But when the exception is raised, the self.func still execute and doesn't terminated.
Please help me :(((

Update for some example of this class used:
i have the function like this:

```
def test():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("3 seconds pass")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("6 seconds pass")
    return 6
```

then when i run this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    performance = Performance(test, 4, 0)
    a = performance.run()
    print(a)
```

you see that the function test() will take a least 6 second to complete (because it sleeps in 6 second) so if i run the with the performance class, i would prefer to have the output:

```
3 seconds pass
TimeoutError: Time Limited Exceeded!
0
```

0 is because the except return is 0 (mean that if there is an exeption, the except_return will be return instead)
how ever, when i run this, the output is:

```
3 seconds pass
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1394, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\btl1\Performance.py", line 20, in handler
    raise TimeoutError("Time Limited Exceeded!")
TimeoutError: Time Limited Exceeded!
6 seconds pass
Executing Time: 6.00133
Memory Used: 69632 bytes
6
```

it show me that the except block seem not to be execute although the exception is raised.
At first time, i think that because the exception is raised in handle function which will execute in another thread but i'm not sure about that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also shared how the class is used - i.e. how the methods are called from main.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry about lack of information. i have just add basic use for the class above.